# Filter markers with multiple data attributes on Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, filter, maps, markers

I tried to make filters for a Google Map API based on the data attributes given to the markers. I made an example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/robvkb/pen/QWbjPXr). Every marker has (in this example) two data attribute:

1. type_po
2. denominatie

Now the problem is that the filters work separately, but I can't combine two filters. E.g. When you check 'SBO' and 'Katholiek', you should only see one marker, but instead you see every marker with either the attribute SBO or the attribute Katholiek.

So my question is: what changes needs to be made so that only the marker(s) appear that are the same as the checked checkboxes combined?

```
/*
Marker Filter
*/

filterMarker = function (id) {
for (i = 0; i < map.markers.length; i++) {
    marker = map.markers[i];

    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        if (marker.type_po == id) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
    }  else {
        if (marker.type_po == id) {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        if (marker.denominatie == id) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
    }  else {
        if (marker.denominatie == id) {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you not come up with a [mcve] (read: *minimal*) instead of 259 lines of JS?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I didn't really know how i could minify my code, because it kept breaking my map. You can find the filters on line 85 till line 110.